# Dictionary custom comparer to get dictinct of custom object

Tags: c#

I want to use my comparer `MyComparer` to be able to get uniques `Vector`s from my dictionary. The problem is the result of uniques is wrong. I tried to put breakpoint inside `MyComparer` but somehow when this line is reached `var uniques = map.Distinct(new MyComparer());` it doesn't goes into `MyComparer` for unknown reason. Why is that? The second point is does the logic inside `MyComparer` enough to compare `Vector`s in my dictionary and get the uniques?

**Filling up dictionary**

```
var map = new Dictionary<Vector, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                map.Add(new Vector { A = s[0, i], B = s[0, i + 1], C = s[1, i], D = s[1, i + 1] }, i);

            var uniques = map.Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

**Vector class:**

```
class Vector
{
            public int A { get; set; }
            public int B { get; set; }
            public int C { get; set; }
            public int D { get; set; }
}
```

**MyComparer**

```
class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<Vector, int>>
{
       public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<Vector, int> x, KeyValuePair<Vector, int> y)
       {
             return x.Key == y.Key;
       }

       public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<Vector, int> obj)
       {
           return 1;
       }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following the logic here. A `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` holds unique keys to begin with...

Comment: Sorry, but what you want to compare: `KeyValuePairs<Vector, int>` or `keys - typeof(vectors)`?

Comment: I want to distinct vector's so for example if there is vector having : A = 1 B = 2 C = 3 D = 4 existing on list more than 1 i want to keep only 1 on my uniques's list.

Comment: "I want to distinct vector's" but keys in a dictionary are unique* **by definition**.
from official documentation: 
*Every key in a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> must be unique according to the dictionary's equality comparer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your not seeing it hit the breakpoint is because you're not "resolving" the IEnumerable.

For example when I run this code:

```
var thing = map.Where(pair => pair.Key == 1);
```

I get an IEnumerable back, it will only resolve the IEnumerable value (or result) once I use the type. The easiest way to do this is just to add a `.ToList();`

```
var uniques = map.Distinct(new MyComparer())
                .ToList();
```

Now your breakpoints should be hit.

Comment: ok, and what i am doing wrong the distinct is not really making dictinsts? I assume my Equal() is bad.

Comment: Well you are just comparing two reference values (which are not going to equate) better to do a `x.Key.A == y.Key.A &&` and so forth

Comment: I did return x.Key.A == y.Key.A && x.Key.B == y.Key.B && x.Key.C == y.Key.C && x.Key.D == y.Key.D; and seems now it's fine. Not sure about GetHashCode() method i have currently there return 1; is this fine?

Comment: Probably worth reading up on the ms docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0